# maven 2.2.1 build error : Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory

Tags: maven, maven-2

When I build the project with maven 2.2.1, it download jar from nexus with https connection.

But it seems there is something wrong while downloading the dependency jar, What's the problem , how to solve it ?

Error:

`[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:po
m:2.2' from repository HTSA_BCD_Team-m2 (http://r2alm.ghq.com:7001/alm/proxy/ht
su/HTSA_BCD_Team-m2): Error transferring file: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory`

Comment: ` Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory` sounds like you are trying to run it under IBM jdk ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know how to solve this.

Edit java.security file which is in jre/lib/security

comment original ssl and set the them below:

ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you

Comment: I am guessing that the JDK bundled with IBM WebSphere is configured to use WebSphere SSL libraries which in turn use WebSphere's cacerts file. To use the IBM JDK's cacerts you need to update that configuration as explained by this answer.

Comment: worked perfectly for mine to connect newly added SSL hosts. Thanks a TON and saving a day.